# Apply a kernel to selected pixels only within an image

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, convolution, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to build a customized DCGAN in PyTorch for a project. The custom part is my own gaussian blur filter on the end of the generator that blurs only pixel values over a certain threshold. The issue is when I add the filter to the forward pass of the generator, the backward() call takes much longer. Without the filter, it's pretty much instant; with the filter, it takes over a minute.

I'm assuming it's the big loop iterating through the image that's causing the problem, is there a way around this?

The forward pass of the generator:

```
def forward(self, x):   
    x = self.gen(x)
    x = convolve2D(x)
    return x
```

The convolve2D function takes a batch and iterates through it selectively applying the filter:

```
def convolve2D(batch, padding=0, strides=1):

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

kernel = torch.tensor(([1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1])).to(device)

kernel_sum = kernel.sum()

# Gather Shapes of Kernel + Image + Padding
xKernShape = kernel.shape[0]
yKernShape = kernel.shape[1]
xImgShape = batch.shape[2]
yImgShape = batch.shape[3]    

copy = batch.clone()

for i, image in tqdm(enumerate(copy)):
    for j, channel in enumerate(image):

        # Apply Equal Padding to All Sides
        if padding != 0:
            channelPadded = torch.zeros((channel.shape[0] + padding*2, channel.shape[1] + padding*2))
            channelPadded[int(padding):int(-1 * padding), int(padding):int(-1 * padding)] = channel
            print(channelPadded)

        else:
            channelPadded = channel

        # Iterate through image
        for y in range(yImgShape):
            # Exit Convolution
            if y > yImgShape - yKernShape:
                break
            # Only Convolve if y has gone down by the specified Strides
            if y % strides == 0:
                for x in range(xImgShape):
                    # Go to next row once kernel is out of bounds
                    if x > xImgShape - xKernShape:
                        break
                    # Ignore if pixel is an edge
                    if channel[x + 1, y + 1] < 0:
                        continue
                    else:
                        # Only Convolve if x has moved by the specified Strides
                        if x % strides == 0:
                            batch[i][j][x + 1, y + 1] = torch.mul(kernel, channelPadded[x: x + xKernShape, y: y + yKernShape]).sum() / kernel_sum
                            
       
return batch
```

Comment: I recommend changing the title to "Apply a kernel to selected pixels only within an image" or something similar. The current title is not uniquely descriptive of your problem

Comment: looks like you are doing masked convolution. check this one out: https://github.com/NVIDIA/partialconv

Comment: I think masked convolution is ever-so-slightly different. Mask convolution assumes an image has some masked pixels and essentially ignores these pixels as inputs entirely. Conversely, in this  problem every input is used, but there are sort of two output procedures depending on the input values. Thus it's a masked output selection problem, not a masked input selection problem.   Section 3.1, this paper:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07723.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for backprop in pytorch a loop over the x and y coordinates of the image will be unbearably slow. Let `original` be `batch[i][j]` and `blurred` be the result when `kernel` is applied non-selectively over `original` in its entirety. For simplicity I'm omitting the code for this as it is trivial as long as the padding results in `original` and `blurred` having the same size.

Now, that you have convolved the kernel over the entire image, simply [selectively choose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) elements from either `blurred` or `original` based on the value in `original`.

```
output = torch.where(original > threshold, blurred, original)
```